# Contar valores de celdas en un renglon MYSQL WorkBench

Tags: mysql-workbench

Qué tal,

Tengo una tabla en la cuál deseo contar los valores que tiene cada celda de un renglón para compararlos con los valores de las celdas de los siguientes renglones. 
Para al final tomar el valor mayor.

Éste es un ejemplo de mi tabla, en la cuál el primer renglón es 15 y el segundo 4 por lo tanto el mayor es 15.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
Select MAX(TiempoP + TiempoH + TiempoN + TiempoB)
FROM Tabla
```

Comment: Hola Bytes Man, aunque esta respuesta puede ayudar a resolver el problema, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Deberías editarla para añadir algo más de detalles (qué hace esa select y por qué solucionaría el problema) y también para darle mejor formato a la publicación. Lee [answer] y [Cómo formatear tus publicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) para más información y recomendaciones.